# jQuery plugin not loading in WordPress

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, plugins

I've successfully linked jQuery to WordPress within the `functions.php`. However, it appears that the `center.js` is not loading. I say this, because the console is giving me this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'center'`

I am calling all scripts with `<?php wp_head(); ?>` within the `header.php`. Here is my `functions.php`:

```
<?php

function add_google_jquery() {
   if ( !is_admin() ) {
      wp_deregister_script('jquery');
      wp_register_script('jquery', ("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js"), false);
      wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
   }
}
add_action('wp_print_scripts ', 'add_google_jquery');

// just added jQuery

function add_google_center() {
   if ( !is_admin() ) {
      wp_register_script('center', ("http://jquerydevbrazil.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jquery.center.js"), false);
      wp_enqueue_script('center');
   }
}
add_action('wp_print_scripts_center ', 'add_google_center');


set_post_thumbnail_size( 800, 600, 1 );

function PA_stylesheet() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'pa-style', get_stylesheet_uri() );

}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'PA_stylesheet' );

function PA_javascript() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-script',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/tran.js',
        array( 'jquery' )
    );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'PA_javascript' );

?>
```

Would anyone be able to help solve this problem?

Comment: Can you paste the contents of trans.js? Is this where your 'center' method is being called?

Comment: Wordpress comes with its own jQuery in wp-includes\js\jquery, why change it against an older version? It might break other plugins or themes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be using wp_print_scripts. Use wp_enqueue_scripts instead.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_print_scripts

(this is for tying in your add_google_jquery and add_google_center functions)

So, all you need to do is replace 'wp_print_scripts' with 'wp_enqueue_scripts' and you should be good to go